# Angular.js filters and functions on scope that is changing every second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

The problem. I have a table of entries(`$scope.entries`), each row(ng-repeat) with 5 columns, 2 of those columns have custom made filter for various transformations.

Now in the same scope I have active_entry(`$scope.active_entry`), which is changing every seconds, because of it and how angular works(I guess), the whole scope is being constantly checked and my filters executed.

This causes **Watch Expressions** in Batarang to go sky high over the time.

How can I use create some sort of isolated scope for the active_entry so my filters are not rended over and over again every second?

Is making a directive the only way to create an isolated scope? Would it work? What if I needed values from the isolated scope later on in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking quite a few questions in your question.  It would be better to ask them each in separate SO questions.

Anytime an [Angular digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime) runs, all watches and filters will run.  Changing things "inside" of Angualar will cause a digest cycle to run.  How are you changing `$scope.active_entry`?  If you can change it outside of Angular, you might be able to do what you want.  As you mentioned, you'll also have to put that property into a new child scope (`scope: true`) or isolate scope (`scope: {...}`), then you could call `$scope.digest()` (after you change `active_entry`) to only digest that scope.

Creating a directive would be the best way to create an isolate scope.  You can create a child scope with ng-controller or a directive.

See also https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/1XtEAX93ces/discussion

Comment: It's sort of a timer, so active_entry is being updated every second with $timeout..

Comment: I don't get it, I created an isolated scope http://plnkr.co/edit/8UqVXWFTdutIQ4sHDPAe?p=preview and filters on parent scope are still being executed every second(check console)..

Comment: Ah I see, the third parameter at $timeout and the $digest().