# Best way to pass variable from controller to directive's isolated scope without adding it to parent's scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry if the title is not the most accurate..
So what I'm trying to do and what are my reasons behind it. I have a list of entries which can be pretty huge, up to 400 items, I get this list from ajax request, now if the **first** item has attribute `running` I want to extract it from the list(by using `splice()`) and pass it to a directive, which can work on it in an *isolated scope*. Why? Because the running entry will have a timer on it, which adds +1 to one of it's attributes each second with `$timeout`.

Now I want it to be isolated because of this [Angular.js filters and functions on scope that is changing every second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15929191/301596) I don't want filters and everything on the list of *not-running* entries to be called every second just because something(timer especially) changed on the running entry.

Now when I press save or something, I want to put the running entry back to the entries, only with `running: false` now.

I kind of know how to inherit object from parent and create an isolated scope from it on the directive - http://plnkr.co/edit/zq3urVh5t6N12T5ZrViO?p=preview

Passing it there this way doesn't really seems ideal, but I was told it was fine and nothing really against best practice.

**Now here comes the problems/question**

1. Is there any way to pass "running" the directive without adding it to the scope, because it's pretty much useless there once it gets copied

   - should I look for a way of passing it without adding it to the scope?
   - or should I deleted it after its copied?
   - or should I leave it because it doesn't matter?
2. if `ENTRIES` are being set with ajax, it's impossible to copy the running one, because it's not yet set - http://plnkr.co/edit/vH3hKbkTkTvcHqykIXDt?p=preview

   - should I have `$watch` inside the directive?
   - or should I use broadcast/on? like this http://plnkr.co/edit/1oPMyxSVMdiN8tB9l1YJ?p=preview
   - or am I doing it wrong completely?

Thanks!

Comment: if you want to pass variable from controller to directive  you have to  set attribute and use attribute inside the scope like scope:{entry:'@items'} for detailed explaination pls see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @ is not going to work for objects, see http://plnkr.co/edit/evst1hkDcoCvvLb8610X?p=preview and I would still have to add the running entry to the scope to be able to pass it to the directive

Comment: its not true just use below code in html

Comment: how is it not true, you are passing it only a string with name in your example..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass complete literal object that you have to use '=' but if you want to use @ then you have to make use of $eval see little example of working

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="obj.name">

    <my-directive obj="obj" title="{{title}}">

      </my-directive>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.obj = { name: "John", surname: "Doe" };
            $scope.title = { name: 'abc' };
        });


         app.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div><span>{{obj.name}}<span><span>{{title}}<span></div>",
            replace: true,
            scope: { title: '@', obj: '=' },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('title', function (value) {
                    alert(scope.$eval(value).name);
                })


            }
        }
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need far more than just the name though, entry will have at least 5 other attributes, that's why I want to pass it the whole entry object.

Comment: i thought you just want to pass one property for complete literal pls use = property

Comment: = would set up bi-directional binding, wouldn't it? Which is again no good for me, I *don't want* directive's scope to affect parent scope. Reasons are in the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: then you have to use scope.eval in the directives

Comment: one other way could be observing the attribute changes as edited above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28168/discussion-between-ajay-beni-and-foxx)

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive to have scope: true - this is then isolated but inherits the parent

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.timer = 0;
            $timeout(function tick() {
                scope.timer = scope.timer+1;
                $timeout(tick, 1000);
            });      
        }
    }
})
```

then in your directive just use it as if it was in the parent scope!

```
<my-directive>
  <h4>"running" entry on directive in isolated scope</h4>
  <p>Timer: {{timer}}</p>
  {{ running | json }}<br/>
  <input type="text" ng-model="running.name" />
</my-directive>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/f5AzfjoEmRT9P1Dw8REj?p=preview